# How get WP e-commerce product height & width?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i'm new to wordpress. i'm developing a wordpress e-commerce theme using WP e-commerce plugin and trying to get the product size information in theme. but it is not happening. you can see here http://screencast.com/t/ajb18CXi. is there any inbuilt wpsc function or something else to do this job??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to get product metadata:

```
$metadata = get_post_meta(wpsc_the_product_id(), '_wpsc_product_metadata', true);
```

And then use it like:

```
$height = $metadata['dimensions']['height'];
$width = $metadata['dimensions']['width'];
...
```